# Seletor CSS para modificar TAG antes ou depois dentro da div

Tags: css, seletores

Estou em dúvida ao aplicar alguns estilos no `css`. Desejo modificar uma `tag` usando uma `div` dentro dela:

```css
header {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    min-height: 64px;
    max-height: 1000px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -ms-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
       -moz-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
        -ms-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
         -o-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1);
    -webkit-transition-property: max-height,box-shadow;
       -moz-transition-property: max-height,box-shadow;
        -ms-transition-property: max-height,box-shadow;
         -o-transition-property: max-height,box-shadow;
            transition-property: max-height,box-shadow;
    background-color: #00bcd4;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

header .drawer-button {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 50px;
    margin: 10px 12px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    color: #ffffff;
    z-index: 4;
}

header .li-row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 15px 0 80px;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-align-self: stretch;
    -ms-flex-item-align: stretch;
    align-self: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header .li-row > * {
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
    -ms-flex-negative: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

header .layout-spacer {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

header .action-drawer {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 64px;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

header .action-drawer > .drawer-button {
    position: inherit;
    margin: inherit;
}

header .layout-spacer > input[type="search"] {
    border: none;
    width: 50%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    color: black;
}

header .layout-spacer > input[type="search"]:focus, input[type="search"]:focus + header.color, header .layout-spacer > input[type="search"]:focus + .color {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
       -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
        -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
         -o-transition: all 0.5s;
            transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<header class="color">
    <div class="drawer-button"></div>
    <div class="li-row">
        <!-- Title -->
        <h1 class="text-title">Title</h1>
        <!-- Center Espace -->
        <div class="layout-spacer">
            <input type="search" class="text-subhead" />
            <div class="color">oi</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Navigation -->
        <div class="action-drawer">
            <div class="drawer-button"></div>
            <div class="drawer-button"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Desejo modificar a cor do `<header>` através do `<input type="search">` sem utilizar `jQuery`, somente utilizando `css`.

Comment: O que queres  realmente fazer?

Comment: Você quer alterar a cor do <header> quando alguém clicar no <input type="search">? se for isso não é possível fazer sem JS pois para tal você precisaria de "parent selectors" (selecionar pais de um elemento) que só existem na spec do css4, a qual ainda é minimamente suportada pelos browsers.

Comment: mudar a cor do `<header>` ao clicar no `<input type="search">` pelo `:focus`

Comment: @iLeonardoCarvalho infelizmente, utilizando APENAS css vai ser impossível, pois o elemento `input` é `child` do elemento `header`, logo, ele não consegue alterar os estilos. Somente um elemento 'pai' pode alterar o elemento 'filho', o inverso não funciona. Você precisa de JS para fazer essa seleção.

Comment: possível então criar um class carregada no `<body>` como elemento pai para eu modificar no `<input type="search">` fazendo a alteração no `<header>`?

Comment: Eu imaginava que se pudesse criar uma regra no CSS como: `header .input:focus + header { ... }` já que a condição é `and` e aplicar no `<header>`, se alguém tiver alguma outra forma estou aberta a sugestões.

Comment: Impossível por hora, se você souber inglês de uma lida neste artigo: http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors , o `CSS4` vai ter o `:has()` que utilizamos hoje na jQuery qual se aplicaria perfeitamente ao seu interesse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o Felipe Assunção informou, não existe um método que modifique uma propriedade em um `parentElement` a partir do `childElement` ainda, isso só estará presente no CSS4... você pode fazer isso tanto com jQuery quanto com javascript puro. Aqui vai um exemplo que montei e que faz exatamente o que você precisa em javascript puro:

```js
var inputSearch = document.querySelector('header input[type=search]');

inputSearch.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('searchfocus');
}, false);

inputSearch.addEventListener('blur', function() {
  this.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.classList.toggle('searchfocus');
}, false);
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat');
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #2b82ad;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
header.searchfocus {
  background: #00405d;
}
header,
header > section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
header button {
  height: 50px;
  min-width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
button:active {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
button,
h1 {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #222;
  user-select: none;
}
button .fa {
  font-size: 150%;
  padding: 5px;
}
header > section {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
header > section > h1 {
  padding: 10px;
}
header > section > nav > input[type=search] {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  border: 1px solid #77B8D8;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  font-size: 90%;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
input[type=search]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
input[type=search]:-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
input[type=search]::-moz-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
input[type=search]:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
input[type=search]::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
input[type=search]:placeholder-shown {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <button><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
  <section>
    <h1 class="text-title">Hello World</h1>
    <nav>
      <input type="search" class="" placeholder="procurar" />
      <button>Sobre</button>
      <button>Contato</button>
    </nav>
  </section>
</header>
```

Comment: Agradeço por me dá um feedback, vou seguir o conselho de todos, já minha preocupação è a compatibilidade entre versões antigas dos navegadores já que temos o CSS3 bem estável, mas usando o JavaScript puro vejo boas soluções. Já vi muitas aplicações usarem o `<input type checkbox>` com `:checked` para ativar menus escondidos pelo `transform: translate`, e fiquei imaginando como evoluiu o CSS acho que vamos chegar numa era que vai ser difícil usar o `JavaScript` :) vou estudar o `CSS4` como o @Felipe mensionou o site e obrigado pelo exemplo @Leandro, eu tava pensando se conpensa fazer no Angular

Comment: Cara, como o que você precisa é bem simples, creio que não seja usual trabalhar com AngularJS para isso. O Angular é melhor para a manipulação de dados... agora, se sua aplicação já contem ele, não vejo problemas em relação a isso...

Comment: Eu tenho umas aplicações no Angular e não sei se misturar linguagens podem afetar no desempenho. Gosto utilizar o Angular devido das rotas e a separação de conteúdo sem preciso carrega-lás novamente e não sei se assim vai atrapalhar eu uso o `UI-Router`.